# Border Color For Toggle Button Does not change?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" x:Key="ListToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF232A2E"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="#FFECECEC" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF232A2E"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFECECEC"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF5F5F5"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF25a0da"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
                            </Trigger>

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I want to change the border color when I checked the button, background changes but border no !

What I miss

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a name for the border, and specify it under `TargetName` in the `Setter`. When you omit `TargetName`, it will set the value of the property of the owner of the trigger (in this case the `ToggleButton` itself). `Background` setter is working because the border's background is template-bound to the togglebutton's background property.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" x:Key="ListToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF232A2E"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="#FFECECEC" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF232A2E"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFECECEC" TargetName="ButtonBorder"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" TargetName="ButtonBorder"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF5F5F5"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF25a0da" TargetName="ButtonBorder"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2" TargetName="ButtonBorder"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) I appropriate your help.